# echo $string work on chrome but not firefox and other

Tags: php

please take a look at this line, if i use chrome click the link is ok http://domain.com/something but i try on firefox or opera etc.. after click the link it show like this http://domain.com\something, the backslash did not change to forward slash, only work on chrome, please help, thanks

```
echo $string = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://domain.com\something\";
```

Comment: echo $string is resolved on the server, so the browser has nothing to do with it. It must be creating an invalid html, like the snippet you posted is (you're not closing the tag)

Comment: You're missing a quote at the end of the string.

Comment: can you show what the resulting HTML looks like from `View Source`?

Comment: @RomanPickl Why wouldn't he? You can see the quotes inside his string.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed last double quoute and your anchor tag is not closed and also you use `\` instead `/` in your link. Try like this:

```
echo $string = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://domain.com/something\" > http://domain.com/something</a>";
```

Comment: @user3150621: Can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
echo $string = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://domain.com/something\";
```

should read

```
echo $string = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://domain.com\something\"";
```

Comment: This is probably a copying error to SO, because he would get a syntax error from PHP with the missing quote.

Comment: But why the backslash _inside_ the url?

Comment: No, I mean domain.com\something , is it correct a backslash there?

Answer (score 0):

Try like,

```
echo $string = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://domain.com/something\">link</a> ";
```

Comment: But why the backslash inside the url?

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes?

`echo $string = '<a target="_blank" href="http://domain.com/something/">link</a>';`

Comment: But why the backslash inside the url?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, that's wrong. Changed to normal slashes. Hmm, and it is indeed a broken link, because it doesn't have a closing </a> tag.

Comment: @Damien thanks for mention about backslash, the backslash change to forwardslash is working now, thanks all of you guys

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
echo $string = "<a target='_blank' href='http://domain.com/something' >http://domain.com/something</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echo $string = "http://domain.com\something\";

echo 'link';

Why $string= ?